# Sum all the values in an object by filtering country attribute - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

I have dataset1.grants which has objects in a form

As you can notice below that **the main object is called grants** which has an important field called **Value** and an object **nested** inside grants called **"organisation"** which has an important **Country** field.

[image: dataset1.grants object example]

I would like to calculate **sum of all the Values by Country**. And there are 500+ objects and 5+ countries. I want to **create an array object** which will have {country:"england", Total_value: 23455623} something like this:

How do I keep on comparing CountryList array that I have with nested object called Organisation.Country and add++ value to the total for a country.

Code So Far:

```
var countries = {};

dataset1.organisations.forEach(function(org)
{
    countries[org.Country]=true      //gets all the countries from dataset and sets it to true in countries object
})
var countryList = [];               //has list of countries in array
for (var key in countries)
{
    countryList.push(key);
}
```

Object

```
{
    "grant": 0,
    "ID": "EP/E027261/1",
    "Title": "Semiconductor Research at the Materials-Device Interface",
    "PIID": "6674",
    "Scheme": "Platform Grants",
    "StartDate": "01/05/2007",
    "EndDate": "31/10/2012",
    "Value": "800579",
    "ResearchArea": "Non CMOS Device Technology",
    "Theme": "Information and Communication Technologies",
    "Department": "Electrical and Electronic Engineering",
    "OrgID": "93",
    "Investigators": [
        {
            "ID": "6674",
            "Role": "Principal Investigator"
        },
        {
            "ID": "29195",
            "Role": "Co Investigator"
        },
        {
            "ID": "90639",
            "Role": "Co Investigator"
        },
        {
            "ID": "101342",
            "Role": "Co Investigator"
        },
        {
            "ID": "12223",
            "Role": "Co Investigator"
        },
        {
            "ID": "45348",
            "Role": "Co Investigator"
        },
        {
            "ID": "96538",
            "Role": "Co Investigator"
        },
        {
            "ID": "10965",
            "Role": "Co Investigator"
        }
    ],
    "Collaborators": [],
    "Summary": "This proposal concerns research into electronic materials, and the development of experimental methods designed to improve our measurement capability on the nm scale.  Semiconductor materials and devices are central to manufacturing, healthcare, security, administration and leisure. This pivotal position in our lives has developed gradually but is due in the main to dramatic changes that have occurred quite recently. Over the last decade semiconductor technology has begun to experience a revolution in terms of functionality based on decreased size and increased complexity, and this trend will define the future for the entire manufacturing sector. This presents immense challenges to both researchers and to manufacturers of semiconductors because the key issues are no longer the properties of bulk materials or even two-dimensional structures but the properties of small heterogeneous clusters of atoms (semiconductor, dielectric and metal) that constitute today's functional device. To put this into context, the next generation silicon NMOS transistor (45nm node) is only half the size of an influenza virus and for most applications will work in conjunction with tens of millions of similar devices. For research, development and control in manufacture the electronic and physical properties of small atomic clusters need to be probed and interactions with structures in close proximity understood.As materials and device sub-structures become more complex the experimental task of obtaining precise information becomes ever more challenging. In particular the atomic organisation and local chemistry can have a profound effect on electronic behaviour and there is a growing need to develop measurement methods which can both image structures and link shape with local spectroscopic information. In our work we are pushing forward such methods by combining x-ray spectroscopy with scanning probe imaging, using both national and international synchrotron radiation sources. In a complementary approach, we are extending electron energy loss techniques in scanning transmission electron microscopy to link chemical and structural information. Optical spectroscopy is an invaluable tool for characterising condensed matter and we are developing free electron laser pumped Raman spectroscopy in order to directly probe electron states in ultra small semiconductors.Almost all emerging device technologies are limited by these materials issues and much of our work is guided by measuring and understanding these. For example, ultra high speed, low noise detectors and amplifiers are desperately needed by radio-astronomers for the next generation of telescopes. Such devices demand near perfect material and interface properties and form part of our programme. Similarly future THz emitters are hugely challenging in terms of materials physics. One of the key developments in electronic materials in the last decade is the ability to synthesise quantum dots which give three dimensional control over quantum size effects and hold the promise of highly tuneable materials. Measuring the collective electrical properties has proved a major task and the information required to build many devices is missing. We are extending and adapting point defect measurement methods to close this gap. The increasing complexity of materials raises many issues for the device and circuit designer. An important feature of our proposed work is that we aim to include device design concepts at the materials level, and will use this work to guide our experimental programme.",
    "organisation": {
        "organisation": 93,
        "OrgID": "93",
        "Name": "The University of Manchester",
        "City": "Manchester",
        "Region": "Greater Manchester",
        "Country": "England",
        "Postcode": "M13 9PL",
        "Latitude": "53.4668498",
        "Longitude": "-2.2338837"
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste object as text, not image. `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4))`

Comment: as per your request I have added the object. please help, I dont know much of javascript. i from java language background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this ES6 script, which uses a `Map` for aggregating the values keyed by country, and then converts that result with `Array.from` to the array of objects you require:

```
var result = Array.from(
    dataset1.grants.reduce( (countries, grant) =>
        countries.set(grant.organisation.Country, 
                      (countries.get(grant.organisation.Country) || 0) + +grant.Value), 
        new Map() ),
    ([country, sum]) => ({ country, sum })
);
```

Snippet with simplified sample data:

```js
var dataset1 = {
    "grants": [{
        "Value": "800579",
        "organisation": {
            "Country": "England"
        }
    },{
        "Value": "100",
        "organisation": {
            "Country": "England"
        }
    },{
        "Value": "200",
        "organisation": {
            "Country": "England"
        }
    },{
        "Value": "1",
        "organisation": {
            "Country": "Belgium"
        }
    }]
};

var result = Array.from(
    dataset1.grants.reduce( (countries, grant) =>
        countries.set(grant.organisation.Country, 
            (countries.get(grant.organisation.Country) || 0) + +grant.Value), 
        new Map() ),
    ([country, sum]) => ({ country, sum })
);

console.log(result);
```

#### Explanation

The code starts with `new Map()`, which creates a [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which can be used to organise data by keys (much like a plain object has key/values). This empty Map is the initial value that will accumulate while `reduce` iterates over the grants and calls the (arrow) function for each grant.

This arrow function uses two arguments: the accumulated value, i.e. the `Map` object (named *countries*) and the current grant object (named *grant*). The Map's `get` method is used to retrieve from that map what we already have for the grant's country. If nothing is found, the `|| 0` will kick in and 0 will be used instead.

To that value the current grant's value is added with `+ +grant.Value`. The second plus is an unitary one that converts a string to a number, since it seemed from your example that the `Value` properties have string values.

This sum is stored back into the Map, using the `set` method, in the entry keyed by the grant's country. The `set` method has a return value which is the whole Map. This is great, since the `reduce` callback must return the accumulated value, and that is our Map. Then `reduce` will call the callback again for the next grant object, and pass as first argument what we returned in the previous call, and so the accumulated Map passes from one iteration to the next. At the final call this return value will become the return value of the `reduce` method itself.

This now completed map has the information you need, i.e. a sum per country. But as you were not looking for a Map, but an array of objects, one more step is executed: `Array.from` can convert a map to an array of pairs (i.e. subarrays with 2 elements). This comes close, but is not yet what you asked for.

Now, `Array.from` accepts a function as its second argument, which allows you to map (translate) each element (pair) to something else. So in this case we translate the pair `[country, sum]` to an object `{country, sum}`. Here we use several ES6 features: one is that we can define function arguments with destructuring syntax, and another one is that we can use a shortcut notation for `{country: country, sum: sum}`.

Some parentheses are necessary in that last arrow function to avoid JavaScript to misinterpret the brackets and/or braces.

Comment: i dont understand certain aspect of code because I am pretty new to javascript. Can you please explain the code with  .reduce , countries.set, + + grant.Value and new map. or the working of it. what is really happening in the code

Comment: I added a section with explanations.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to constructing a histogram. I recommend doing a google search on the different ways to use histograms, it's educational.

In your case this is how I would accomplish the task.

```
var countries = dataset1.reduce(function(countryList, currentGrant) {
  var country = currentGrant.organisation.Country;
  var value = currentGrant.Value;

  if (!countryList[country]) countryList[country] = 0;
  countryList[country] += value;
  return countryList;
}, {});
```

Now that you have the data in {country1: value1...} format you can construct whatever data structure you'd like.

```
var countries = [];
for (country in countryList) { 
  countries.push({country: country, totalValue: countryList[country]});
}
```